# When to use Permutations or Combinations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

Suppose I have a bundle of crayons, I have 5 different colours of crayon (Blue, Black,   Brown, Red, Grey) how many unique bags can I create with 10 items per bag such that each bag has at least one of each crayon in each bag.

Now my question is can one use permutations and/or combinations...

If that is the case then is it an independent or dependent? Also how does one know when to use permutations and when to use combinations?

EDIT:

So this is how I went about doing it:

```
10 C 5 =  10!/(10-5)! 5!
=(10*9*8*7*6)/(5*4*3*2*1)
= 252
```

Would this be the correct way of going about doing this question?

Comment: Firstly, 'independant' is correctly spelled "independent". Same for "dependent". Secondly, you only provide 4 colours of crayons...

Comment: @ChrisK.. thanks for the prompt reply... I will edit the spelling... Also I will add another colour.

Comment: With permutations, "order matters". So, in this case, we should probably use permutations. As for knowing when to use either one, I usually intuit it. The only thing I ever get wrong is mixing up the definitions of the two; I have to sit down and think about it.

Comment: @ChrisK .. so it is true that we should use permutations in this case  ! :D

Comment: Yes, we should.

Comment: @Chris: I’m afraid that your advice is wrong: there is no question of order, and permutations are not wanted here.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, "order matters" since the case where there is a blue crayon in the first bag and a black crayon in the other four is equivalent to a blue crayon in the fifth bag with black in the others. As for a solution, that was my first intuition, but it doesn't necessarily mean it is always the right approach as I can readily see by looking at the solution.

Comment: @Chris: That’s not really a question of order in the sense relevant to the choice between permutations and combinations, however. Part of the problem here is that many instructors oversimplify by trying to reduce everything to permutations vs. combinations. It would be more helpful to get students to ask whether they’re counting sets of things or tuples of things, and even that is a bit misleading with a problem like this one. Here we’re not obviously counting either one, so it’s better to recognize this as a distinct type of problem.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, thanks for your response. I agree full-heartedly. When I took an introductory stats course, I always answered the problems using intuition and not by trying to classify the problem. In retrospect, I can see how my advice was misleading...

Answer (score 4):

Permutation can be thought of number of ways to order "something", while Combination is the number of ways of selecting "something".

Permutation = Selecting + Ordering.

Thinking along these lines has helped me reduce confusion in many PnC problems.
I always tackle problems by selecting the items and than ask "Does the order matter?" If the answer is "Yes", permuate the answer by multiplying with apt factorial. If "No", you've arrived at the answer you needed.

Example: Let us assume there are 10 people waiting on a bus stop. Now a vehicle comes and there is space of 4 people on it. So the number of ways 4 people can get on the vehicle is 10 C 4, whereas the number of ways they can be seated is 10 P 4.

I hope this helps in visualization of further problems. As for this particular problem, Brian has explained it adequately.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$, and $x_5$ be the numbers of blue, black, brown, red, and grey crayons in a bag. You’re looking for the number of solutions in positive integers to the equation

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=10\;.$$

This is a standard [stars-and-bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29); the linked article gives you both a formula and a fairly decent explanation and derivation of that formula. There should be enough there for you to finish the problem, but feel free to leave a comment if you get stuck.

(Stars-and-bars problems crop up in many different disguises; after a while you learn to spot them. They involve combinations, not permutations, but it’s more useful, I think, to view them as a class of problems in their own right.)

Comment: Hello Brian !

Thanks for the follow up it really helped ! :D ... So I tried to follow your advice and here is what I got... the answer is 252 different combinations. I have shown how I did it in my edited  in the question

Comment: @Martin: Not quite: in the notation of the article, we have here $k=10$ and $n=5$, so there are $\binom{10-1}{5-1}=\binom94=126$ solutions in positive integers.